# Setting up nginx redirect map: how to handle spaces

Tags: redirect, rewrite, url, mapping

How can you handle spaces in the original url in a redirect map? The map I have set up seems to be working properly for other redirects.

However, for urls with spaces, I tried:
`‘/banner ads.htm’   /links/link-humor-times/;`

…but that’s not working. How do you handle spaces?

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to make your post more readable  and post complete config excerpts, not just fragments of a line. Also, look into the log files and post log excerpts when helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution. Just substitute `%20` for the spaces, and don't use quote marks.

This works: `/banner%20ads.htm   /links/link-humor-times/;`

I didn't try it before because I'd read in a forum that it wouldn't work with nginx, but it does.